# How to map a particular field in firestore database

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

For example, if I have the fields like
empId,empName in Employees collection and
empName,city in another collection called EmployeeCities
If I change the empName in the Employees collection, the change should reflect in EmployeeCities. 
I know I can update them manually but, I am asking if we can map certain fields as in SQL primary key and foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore is a NoSQL database, (not a relational database), which means it doesn't enforce relationships between documents and collections.  You cannot designate fields as primary or foreign key.  Any relationship between documents and collection are those that you impose for yourself in your source code.  The database will not enforce them for you.

Comment: Obviously, but if in case I have products collection, users collection and homeproducts collection, user adds products to homeproducts collection from products collection what if the price of the product changes in products collection? Will I have to rewrite the price in every document for every user on homeprodcuts?

Comment: Yes, you will have to re-write every related document (by your definition of relation) that needs to change. This is one downside of nosql type databases.  The upside is that you perform queries against massive collections (billions of documents) without worrying about performance.